Add text over an arrow in tikz
so I am relatively new to tikz and basically just copy&pasted a way, to add arrows in a tabular. The code looks like this
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor{blue1!60}\cellcolor{blue1}\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Personen}} & \quad \quad 4\tikzmark{a}  \quad \quad & \quad \quad \tikzmark{g} 2\tikzmark{b}  \quad \quad & \quad \quad 6\tikzmark{c}  \quad \quad \\ \hline
\rowcolor{blue1!60}\cellcolor{blue1}\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Tage}} &  9\tikzmark{d} & \tikzmark{h} 18\tikzmark{e} & 6\tikzmark{f} \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.9pt, transform canvas={yshift=2\baselineskip}]
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) [bend left=70] to ({pic cs:g});
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:b}) [bend left=70] to ({pic cs:c});
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.9pt, transform canvas={yshift=-1.2\baselineskip}]
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:d}) [bend right=70] to ({pic cs:h});
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:e}) [bend right=70] to ({pic cs:f});
  \end{tikzpicture}

Which gives me this output

Now I wanted to add some text above my arrows, in the end I would like to have it look like this

Is there any easy way to add this text to my arrow or is there a way to do this better?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You could add a node to your arrows like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) to[bend left=70] node[auto] {:2} (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}



Hi, thats a great idea, thanks, and it looks way easier than what I did there. However the node appears exactly, where I put it in the text, is there any command to tell the node "you must start at this point right here"?

@ChristianDeter The node will by default be in the centre of the arrow. Isn't this what your image shows?

oh yeah you are right, sorry i misunderstood what a node actually is. it works now, thanks
